# Unable to pass the value from a variable/JSON file in the payload

Tags: karate

I am trying to pass a value inside below payload, I am able to get the value of it from the print but same is not accessible inside the payload, It prints the #(config.Secondary_ED) as the output.
The ***config.Secondary_ED*** contains an ip address. It works fine when I give ip address manually.

```
    And print config.Secondary_ED
    And request {"agent-forwarding":true,"configuration-data":"{\"service-host\":\"#(config.Secondary_ED)\",\"service-port\":\"8443\",\"user\":\"restdispatcher\",\"protocol\":\"vosrestdispatcher:rest\"}","configuration-template":null,"description":"Change Guardian Default Event Destination sk-12sp5","display-name":"sk-12sp5","ev-prototype-id":"1","forwarding-queries":[""],"id":1,"is-default":true,"is-indelible":true,"method":"vosrestdispatcher:rest","model":"REST Dispatcher","server-fordwarding":false}     
    When method PUT
```

Working Payload

```
    #And print config.Secondary_ED
    And request {"agent-forwarding":true,"configuration-data":"{\"service-host\":\"1.1.1.1\",\"service-port\":\"8443\",\"user\":\"restdispatcher\",\"protocol\":\"vosrestdispatcher:rest\"}","configuration-template":null,"description":"Change Guardian Default Event Destination sk-12sp5","display-name":"sk-12sp5","ev-prototype-id":"1","forwarding-queries":[""],"id":1,"is-default":true,"is-indelible":true,"method":"vosrestdispatcher:rest","model":"REST Dispatcher","server-fordwarding":false}
```

****Secondary_ED is stored in a json file called config.js**

I have used # many times to get the value but same doesn't work in this case.
Please suggest what did I miss here.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: next time please simplify your example and don't force us to read your full payload. please respect the time of others

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that the value of `configuration-data` is a string, not JSON object. Ask a friend who knows JS if this is not clear.

You can try this (note the usage of `string`):

```
* string configData = { 'service-host': '#(config.Secondary_ED)' }
* request { foo: '#configData' }
```

Or just use JS string concatenation (this is just a guess, please figure out what works for you, but you get the idea.

```
* def configData = '"{\\"service-host\\":\\"' + config.Secondary_ED + '\\"'
```